# Magento 2 get custom product attribute

Tags: magento2, cart, product-attribute, quoteitem, cart-items

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load('YOUR PRODUCT ID');
echo $product->getAttributeText('your_attribut');
```

I need to get product in carts with custom attribute values to pass in a XML for a API POST call I am making.

Say I dont have the product ID, and I just want to get the product in cart with custom attribute value, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like below:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribut', 'your_value');
```

You got the collection. Now you can look through and get what you need. you can also set attribute to select like this:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(*);
```

This is just to explain. In real implementation you should not directly use the ObjectManager but use constructor injection for using the Product Model.

Comment: yes, I know and I already suggested if you read the complete answer that I have written but I don't know how and where it needs to be implemented so just explained using the same pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get custom attribute value of product collection.

```
$products = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(20);
echo '<pre>';
echo count($products);
foreach ($products as $product) {
// print_r($product->getData());
echo $product->getDisplayFlag();
}
echo '</pre>';
```

And If you know the product id and want to get custom attribute value.

```
$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(8041);
echo $product->getCustomAttribute('display_flag')->getValue();
//echo $product->getDisplayFlag();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get Product custom attribute by product id**

here, below code "battery_type" is my custom multiselect attribute. foreach loop used for mutiple value if selected in this attribute field so last coma (,) removed using for each loop.

```
$productId = "2"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

    echo $product->getName()."<br>"; 
    echo $product->getPrice()."<br>";
    $battery_type = $product->getAttributeText('battery_type');

$s = '';
$n = count($battery_type);
foreach ($battery_type as $i => $result) { 
    $s .= $result;
    if (($i+1) != $n) $s .= ' , ';
}
echo $s;
```